# Can't link using MinGW and SDL: undefined reference to WinMain@16

Tags: mingw, sdl-2

I'm not getting MinGW's g++ to successfully compile SDL programs.  Here's my sample program:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{  
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
}
```

and here's my command and error report:

```
C:\Users\briggs_w\Desktop\testSDL>g++ test.cc -IC:\MinGW\include\SDL 
-LC:\MinGW\lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lmingw32

C:\MinGW\lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I copied over everything in SDL2's `lib\x64` and `i686-w64-mingw32\lib` folders to the `C:\MinGW\lib` folder.

What's missing?  At the command line, maybe.

I did look over two threads on similar errors:

[Undefined reference to WinMain@16 when using SDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115153/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-when-using-sdl) -- doing this

[undefined reference to WinMain@16 C++, SDL-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342285/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-c-sdl-2) -- no effect

Comment: `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, exactly in that order (and all src/obj before libs, of course).

Comment: That worked great.  I'd accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I compiled your code so that compiler and linker flags were provided by `sdl2-config` (included in an msys2 package):

```
gcc -O -Wall test.cpp `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
```

> $ sdl2-config --cflags
>
> -I/mingw64/include/SDL2 -Dmain=SDL_main
>
> $ sdl2-config --libs
>
> -L/mingw64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows

So at least `-lmingw32` is in other position in libraries to be linked and also `-Dmain=SDL_main` was missing. The library SDL2main is a static library, so it needs mingw32 to be prior to it when linking.

From [SDL FAQ for windows](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows)

> You should be using main() instead of WinMain() even though you are
>   creating a Windows application, because SDL provides a version of
>   WinMain() which performs some SDL initialization before calling your
>   main code. If for some reason you need to use WinMain(), take a look
>   at the SDL source code in src/main/win32/SDL_main.c to see what kind
>   of initialization you need to do in your WinMain() function so that
>   SDL works properly.

If there is something like *sdl2-config* available in case of any library, I would at least check what it outputs.

Comment: If that was the case, then there would have been 'undefined reference to SDL_main', but it isn't.

Comment: @keltar my guess is that `-mwindows` translates `main` to be `WinMain`, and then `WinMain` in SDL2main library is discarded as duplicate and won't be referenced, and thus SDL_main won't be referenced.

Comment: No, libmingw32.a references WinMain, and cannot find one. ld linker is sensitive to libraries order, especially when libraries are static. Your order is correct so it linked; order in question isn't.

Comment: @keltar yes, I just that checked that myself i.e. that `-lmingw32` and its position was different in the question and what `sdl2-config --libs` gives. I did not notice that difference when writing the answer.